# Ending an Ember application

Tags: ember.js

What's the proper way to end an Ember application?

In my application, I have a logout button.  When pressed, the app sends a message to the server, which terminates the user session and does some cleanup.  On the client side, I currently just transition to the login route, which doesn't really terminate the application since artifacts from the prior login remains.  Hitting the refresh button manually would do it.  Does Ember provide a function to programmatically refresh a page?  Is there a more elegant way of doing this than a refresh?

Comment: This thread on github might be useful: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you'd need to do.

To reset Ember itself you can just use `App.reset();`

Reset any client side record management software (this is different for Ember Model/Ember Data).

Ember doesn't provide a way to programmatically refresh a page, since you can just use `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: From post in Sarus's comment above, sounds like core-team members are also recommending App.reset().  But for some reason, API documentation says App.reset() is typically only used in tests.  I'm using Ember Data.  From the DS.store API documentation, seems like the only function that may work is to call 'unloadAll' on all the types.  Do you recommend this?

Comment: Yeah, resetting the application is a fringe case for sure for normal application usage.  It makes the most sense during testing.  `unloadAll` is a per type method and executed against the store.  This means you'll need to execute it for each record type in the store.